# Advanced filter with multiple criteria

Tags: vba, excel

Does anyone know how after applying the advanced filter in the code below, I can apply another one in col E to show unique values on the filtered data (without getting rid of what is already filtered?) - Any help would be much appreciated

```
Sub difficultQ()

    Dim x
    Dim Y

    x = "Match"

    Y = "Match1"

    Range("A1").Value = x

    Range("A2").Value = Y

    Range("M4").Select

    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select

    Selection.AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, criteriarange:=Range("A1:A2")

    ' In here I would like to have code that filtered col E
    ' on unique values, without getting rid of the advanced filter above

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't apply two advanced filters. You'd need to amend the filter criteria and use a formula for example like this:

```
Sub difficultQ()

    Dim x
    Dim Y
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Y = "Match1"

    Range("A1").Value = vbNullString

    Range("A2").Formula = "=AND(M5=""" & Y & """,COUNTIFS($E$5:$E5,E5,M$5:M5,""" & Y & """)=1)"
    lastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "M").End(xlUp).Row
    Range("E4:M" & lastRow).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, criteriarange:=Range("A1:A2")

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much Rory! This solves the issue perfectly.